# Initialize map from existing map

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-map

Say we have an existing Map:

```
const m1 = new Map([['color', 'red'], ['owner', 'Flavio'], ['age', 2]])
```

if we want to create a new map, is it enough to do:

```
const m2 = new Map(m1);
```

or maybe instead:

```
const m2 = new Map(Array.from(m1))
```

Comment: If you want to create a new Map, you can indeed pass the constructor a previous `Map` like `new Map(m1);`, have you run into any problems using that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance nah no problems so far just making sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN says you could do this.

```js
const first = new Map([
  [1, "one"],
  [2, "two"],
  [3, "three"]
]);

const second = new Map([
  [1, "uno"],
  [2, "dos"],
  [3, "tres"]
]);

const merged = new Map([...first, ...second]);

console.log(merged.get(1))
```